# Comportamiento inesperado en Error en "list group" con Bootstrap 5: las listas se renderizan sobre la NavBar

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Tengo este comportamiento en las listas de bootstrap al bajar o subir, las listas pasan por encima de la navbar.
¿Alguna idea para solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CSS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A ciegas, sin código que revisar, no podremos ayudarte pues no sabemos como has puesto esas listas y como esta el navbar para que te ocurra eso. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender a realizar mejores preguntas que merezcan mejores respuestas.

Comment: ¡El código siempre _como texto, con formato_! Pensalo: ¿cómo depurarías código de una imagen? Subir imágenes de código es mala idea. [He aquí los porqués](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sin código es difícil, te diría de verificar sus propriedades z-index en css.

Comment: ¡Ya tienes reputación suficiente como para dejar comentarios!

Comment: Me sirvió, le añadí: 
" z-index: 999 "
Pero al Navbar